# Newbie needing help with dowloading and using iTunes please

Tags: wine, music, itunes

I am new to Ubuntu and want to download my iTunes music onto my laptop that runs Ubuntu 20.04.3, however after a lot of messing around and using my terminal with code language, I finally found the iTunes icon on the desktop. I tried to open it and it doesn't work :-(

I have installed Wine and Gecko which I thought would open iTunes but it hasn't helped.
Could someone please help me and explain in really "dummy" language how to get it working.

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: In all honesty, iTunes doesn't work well in WINE.  It really is designed for running in Windows that allows it full hardware access to access your iPhone/iPod/iPad...

Comment: Thank you Terrance, any ideas what the best software to use so I can download purchased music and copy my purchases to a USB, all using Ubuntu?

Comment: I mean, you can do it, like according to https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-itunes-on-linux-such-as-ubuntu-20-04-lts/ but you will probably end up with issues accessing your hardware, but you should be able to access your purchased music OK.

Comment: advice: Extract your purchased music from itunes by whatever is the current means (back when I did it it was by burning it to cd), copy the mp3s onto your pc and use native Ubuntu apps.

Comment: Thank you Terrance / Organic Marble for you suggestions and advice. I think the safest way to move forward is to save my music from an apple device that runs iTunes onto a USB, and then put it on my Ubuntu laptop which may be the easiest option. However, how do I get all the iTunes junk I just downloaded onto my laptop as I would rather it not be in the background using precious memory and ram.

Comment: @Kabby it won't be in RAM or "memory" (which is the same as RAM) if you aren't running it.  WINE applications don't have autostart functionality.

Comment: iTunes incompatibility isn't a Linux bug, it's a carefully-designed Apple *feature* that you paid them for with each music purchase. When you run into problems and want to complain, recall who you paid your money to (not us).

Comment: Advice: Don't use any Apple technology. You will get locked into their infrastructure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in

Comment: A big THANK YOU to all the comments/answers regarding my question. Taking into account all the information provided, I have decided that if I need to do anything in my iTunes account, I'll use a Mac, and not my Ubuntu laptop!   :-)